# How to convert signature to data:image/png;base64 in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, signature

I am using react-signature-tab component

```
<div className="form-group row">
 <label className="col-sm-2 form-control-label text-xs-right"> Witness-1 Signature: </label>
 <div style= {{backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1'}}>
  <SignaturePad clearButton="true" />

</div>

 <label className="col-sm-2 form-control-label text-xs-right"> Witness-2 
 Signature: </label>
<div style= {{backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1'}}>
<SignaturePad clearButton="true" />
</div>

 </div>
```

[After signing from this component on click on submit I need to convert the image into "data:image/png;base64, {{imagedata}}"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYI0u.png)
I have gone through the document of react-signature-pad for getting the signature as data url i need to make use of signature.toDataURL();.

I am new to this component I am not able to find the exact solution how to use this method toDataURl().

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Looks like you need to set a `ref` on `SignaturePad` (`ref={"witnessOne"}`) then call `this.refs.witnessOne.toDataURL()`. The Documentation for this seems pretty clear on that usage: https://github.com/blackjk3/react-signature-pad

Comment: I already tried that bro still i did not achieve anything
<SignaturePad clearButton="true" ref="mySignature"/>
                                            <button type="submit" className=" ml-2 mr-0 btn btn-primary" onClick={this.refs.mySignature.toDataURL()}> Submit </button>

Comment: That looks ok; your `onClick` function should convert it to a data url, but it doesn't look like you're doing anything with it in that function.

Comment: showing cannot read property toDataURL